# How can we resume a download even if the link cannot be resumed?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, download-manager

When am downloading any link that's cannot be resumed, if my Internet connection gets disconnected then download link stops working.

What can I do to resume the download from the link?

Answer (score 3):

If the remote host really doesn’t support resume, then there’s not much you *can* do. However, what you can at least try is to use WGET. There are plenty of Windows builds ([here’s one](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/)).

1. (Make a backup copy of the incomplete file)
2. Open a command-prompt (`Win+R -> cmd.exe -> OK`)
3. Drag-and-drop `WGET.EXE` to the command-prompt window
4. Type `-c` (spaces before)
5. Type `-O` (space before)
6. Drag-and-drop the incomplete file to the command-prompt window
7. Copy the URL to the file to the clipboard
8. Click the command-prompt window and press `Space, Alt+Space, E, P, Enter`

You should now be running WGET with a command line such as

```
> C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\wget.exe -c -O "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\cool file.zip" "http://foobar.org/cool file.zip"`
```

If it is possible to resume, it will do so; if not, then it will download from scratch, but will probably do so with less chance of failing.

Comment: It's `-O file`, not `-o=file` (the lowercase `-o` is for saving the _download log_, and it would save it to `=file`).

Answer (score 2):

I used to use [getright](http://getright.com/), but that was in the dial-up days. It supports resuming downloads.

What you're looking for is called a download manager. Some servers just don't support resuming downloads if I remember correctly; however, some of the newer download managers may have found a way around this by now.

Comment: If the server _refuses_ to skip over the first X megabytes and always starts sending from start of file, there's nothing a download manager can do about it (aside from downloading the entire file to another server).

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented feature of this in IE8. If this is a requirement, I would recommend to use another browser such as Mozilla Firefox and add one of the many add-ons such as Download Statusbar.

Though [one article](http://www.ithinkdiff.com/hidden-internet-explorer-feature-resume-your-downloads/) on the interweb claims that it is a hidden feature though I have not been able to proove it.

Comment: Two parts are need for it to work (AFAIK).  The client (be it a browser or download manager) & the server both must support resume, or else there will be no resume.  So whether IE8 does or does not, or if Mozilla does won't matter if the server does not support resume too.